# Fractions vs Decimal numbers

Tags: fractions

I want to know if there is any difference between Fractions and Decimal numbers, are Decimal numbers just Fractions that are written in a different way according to a predefined rule: using "a group of Fractions" that each have a denominator that is smaller 10 times than the one before it.

Comment: It depends on what definitions you are using for those two terms. Sometimes, people use "fraction" to mean any real number between zero and one; sometimes, people use "fraction" to mean something of the form $a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ integers, $b$ positive. Gilles and I use different definitions of "decimal number". What definitions do you have in mind?

Comment: I say, WHAT DEFINITIONS DO YOU HAVE IN MIND?

Comment: Decimals are simply fractions where the divisor is some power of 10. For example $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{25}{100}$ usually written a $0.25$ and common knowledge lets us know that it is $25$ divided by $100$. If you type a decimal into a cell in Excel and then go to format cells, number and then select fraction 2-digit, you will see, for example. that $0.351\approx \frac{33}{94}$

Answer (score 1):

[edited after reading the comments]

I think I learned as a child that a decimal number is a real number that can be written in the form $a/10^b$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$. With this convention there exist rational numbers which are not decimal, *e.g* $1/3=0.3333...$

But after seeing the comments and having a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) it seems this is not the most common definition. So if we consider that

- A decimal number is any real number. The term decimal refers only that we are representing it in base ten.
- A rational number is a real number that can be written in the form $a/b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq0$.

Then any rational number is a decimal number. But there exist decimal number which are not rational, *e.g* $\sqrt{2}=1.414...$.

Comment: Maybe we are using different definitions of "decimal number", but I would say $0.333\dots$ is a decimal number; I'd also say $\sqrt2=1.41421356\dots$ is a decimal number that can't be written as a fraction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Now we've reached a point where we need to agree on a definition of decimal numbers to continue, specifically whether our definition allows infinite sequences of digits.